# script for changing file dates of postfix Mailbox files

Tags: postfix, bash, perl, sed

I have a Maildir structure, that got wrongly restored from backup and all files have the file date of the restore instead of when they have been created/received.

What would be the best way to correct this?

I think about recursively reading the first Received: line, extracting the date and touching the files, but it's a bit above my perl/shell skills. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Something to get you started:

```
#/bin/bash 
for file in *; do
    echo "Processing $file.."
    tstamp=$(grep "^Date:" $file | cut -d : -f 2)
    echo "Set date to $tstamp"
    # I don't know it the date is in the correct format..   
    touch -d "$tstamp" "$file" 
done
```

Comment: This is a good starting point. But Date-Headers are sometimes forged and are in different timezones. Sometimes the date header is missing. Better look into the topmost Received-Header.